# Relativistic Control Theory

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control

I am looking for literature that combines General relativity and control theory.

So far I found a video lecture on "Integrability meets Control Theory: Harmonic maps in GR", other than that not so much.

I assume that control theory applies GR for everything that includes gravity, even if for every practical purpose Newtonian mechanics is enough.

Answer (score 6):

1. [Maximum
   Mass of a Neutron Star](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.32.324) (1974)
2. [Control
   theory and singular Riemannian geometry](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-5651-9_2) (1982)
3. [The
   Condition of Hydrostatic Equilibrium of Stellar Models Using Optimal
   Control](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1021684407650?LI=true#page-1) (2002)
4. [Investigating a model of
   optimized active galactic nucleus feedback](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0548) (2011)

Answer (score 5):

There is also

> [Inverse problems in spacetime I: Inverse problems for Einstein equations - Extended preprint version](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4503), by Yaroslav Kurylev, Matti Lassas, Gunther Uhlmann

and related papers.

Sounds like something different, but from a technical viewpoint inverse problems and optimal control are very similar. In optimal control you interpret some parameter as a control that you want to choose optimally to achieve a specific goal, while in inverse problems you interpret it as an unknown quantity that you like to identify from given measurements. Technically you can turn an optimal control problem into an inverse problem by replacing "control" by "unknown quantity" and "goal" by "measurements" (and vice versa).